# how to give label in matrix on only row

Tags: matrices

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
    top=1.75cm, % Top margin
    bottom=3.5cm, % Bottom margin
    left=3.25cm, % Left margin
    right=3.25cm, % Right margin
        footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document}
$$
=\frac{1}{3}\left( \begin{gmatrix}
    \quad 2 & 1 & -1 \\
    \quad 5 & -2 & -4  \colops
     %\colops
\def\colmultlabel#1{\makebox[1.2em]{$#1$}}
\mult0{L_1}
\mult1{L_3}
\mult2{L_5}
     \end{gmatrix}
     \right)
     $$
\end{document}
```

I have got this one:

[image: result]

But here is the label "L1","L2",and "L3" within the matrix. But i want to place it form the outside of the matrix braces.

Comment: do you want a transposed (3 x 2) matrix? Do you want to keep the letters L1, L2, L3 and put them into the first column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should consider the more modern `nicematrix` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
-\frac{1}{3}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row]
L_1 & L_2 & L_3 \\
2 & 1 & -1 \\
5 & -4 & -2
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The version using `\bordermatrix` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[-\frac{1}{3}
\bordermatrix{
& L_1 & L_2 & L_3\cr
& 2 & 1 & -1 \cr
& 5 & -4 & -2 \cr
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another option using [`kbordermatrix`](//ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix). Note the difference from the previous code. With this package, the labels outside the matrix are smaller. More information on formatting can be found in the [`kbordermatrix` documentation](https://kcborder.caltech.edu/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(} 
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)} 
\begin{document}
\[
  -\frac{1}{3} \kbordermatrix{
    \mbox{} & L_1 & L_2 & L_3 \\
    & 2 & 1 & -1 \\
    & 5 & -4 & -2
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]